# Hints for a web designer learning RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, osx-lion, jruby

I'm learning Ruby and Rails and I am installing the `RVM` in my `Mac / OS X Lion`.

Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that Gems are just simple libraries that you install when you need them for a particular problem. 
Rails for example brings a lot of gems with it by default, and once you need something more you simply add that to your Gemfile.

You just go ahead and install whatever gem you need *to solve a problem*. 
There is this awesome little site called [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) that gives you a listing of the most used RubyGems for solving different problems, but you usually only select one once you actually have a problem.

For starting out with Rails you won't need anything besides Rails.